# a patient was told to use their medication, “ every THREE days”. Does that mean, on the forth day, or the third?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Quote; a patient was told to use their medication every THREE days for pain.
Does that statement mean; on the THIRD day, or the FORTH day ?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: First that sounds like an answer, rather than a comment; secondly, your numbers do not line up (the first iteration to the second iteration is off).

Answer (score 2):

The regime presumably starts as soon as the patient gets the medicine; and every three days thereafter.

So, day 1, 4, 7 ...

Comment: Hi, so your answer implies, it is every THIRD day, and so on —

Comment: +1: However, since this involves the taking of medicine, it is probably a good idea to contact a physician (or at least a pharmacist) for clarity on that patient's specific prescription, rather than taking internet advice that is predicated on general grammatical principals.

Comment: Is day one of the perscription inclusive in the THREE day cycle of every THIRD day ? So the patient would presume that after three days they take the next “ dose”, so to speak ?

Comment: That is what I would assume, @GrantHudson. Any other assumption just looks perverse to me.

Comment: A responsible physician would write, "Every 72 hours." This is unambiguous.